# ASP.NET Core IIS return DefaultAppPool instead of window user name

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-10

I have used System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString(); to get window user name in development mode but when I deploy it to IIS, it returns DefaultAppPool instead of window user name. I have enabled both window authentication an anonymous authentication in development mode.

Comment: Hi Chris and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's a question and answer site about programming. Do you have a question about programming? Please create a minimum reproducible example of the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you combine the knowledge from https://blog.lextudio.com/the-basic-facts-about-iis-asp-net-process-thread-identities-835eaac876a0 and https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 then the cause should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` is the identity under which the thread is running.

If you want to get the window user, please disable anonymous authentication.

Then use:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: I use both anonymous authentication and window authentication, hence this method not working for me, possible to suggest other method?

Comment: If anonymous authentication and windows authentication are both enabled, how the application get the user name when the user authen with anonymous? As far as I know, no method can get user name in anonymous authentication.